# Creating png/pdf with highcharts-export-server error

Tags: node.js, npm, highcharts

I installed node.js LTS version 18.17.1 (includes npm 9.6.7).

```
prompt$ node 
Welcome to Node.js v18.17.1.

prompt$ npm version
npm version
{
  npm: '9.6.7',
  node: '18.17.1',
  acorn: '8.8.2',
  ada: '2.5.0',
  ares: '1.19.1',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  cldr: '43.0',
  icu: '73.1',
  llhttp: '6.0.11',
  modules: '108',
  napi: '9',
  nghttp2: '1.52.0',
  nghttp3: '0.7.0',
  ngtcp2: '0.8.1',
  openssl: '3.0.10+quic',
  simdutf: '3.2.12',
  tz: '2023c',
  undici: '5.22.1',
  unicode: '15.0',
  uv: '1.44.2',
  uvwasi: '0.0.18',
  v8: '10.2.154.26-node.26',
  zlib: '1.2.13.1-motley'
}
```

Then I installed highcharts-export-server :

```
git clone https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server
cd node-export-server
npm install
npm link
```

All seems to be fine without any error

Then I use this test.js file as input (found as a working example at http://export.highcharts.com) :

```
{
"xAxis":
{"categories":
    ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
},
"series":
[
    {"data":[1,3,2,4],"type":"line"},
    {"data":[5,3,4,2],"type":"line"}
]
}
```

Then I launch this command line :

```
export OPENSSL_CONF=/dev/null && highcharts-export-server --nologo 1 --logLevel 4 --infile test.js --outfile test.png --type png --width 500
```

It produces this error and a png (or pdf) output file :

```
phantom worker 1 unexpected data - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'
```

Here is the full error output :

```
starting highcharts export server v2.1.0...
Wed Aug 30 2023 10:41:13 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) [verbose] attaching exit listeners to the process..
Wed Aug 30 2023 10:41:13 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) [verbose] Pool started: 
    maxWorkers: 1 
    initialWorkers: 1 
    workLimit: 60 
    listening to process exit: true
Wed Aug 30 2023 10:41:13 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) [verbose] phantom 1 - spawning worker
Wed Aug 30 2023 10:41:13 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) [verbose] starting export
Wed Aug 30 2023 10:41:13 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) [verbose] attempting to export from input file
Wed Aug 30 2023 10:41:13 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) [verbose] phantom - received work, finding available worker
Wed Aug 30 2023 10:41:13 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) [verbose] phantom - found available worker
Wed Aug 30 2023 10:41:13 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) [verbose] phantom 1 - starting work
Wed Aug 30 2023 10:41:15 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) [error] phantom worker 1 unexpected data - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'

  phantomjs://code/worker.js:658 in loop
{"filename":"test.png"} {
  data: {
    allowCodeExecution: false,
    width: '500',
    callback: false,
    resources: false,
    scale: 1,
    constr: 'Chart',
    chart: {
      xAxis: [Object],
      series: [Array],
      chart: [Object],
      exporting: [Object]
    },
    svgstr: undefined,
    format: 'png',
    out: 'test.png',
    styledMode: false,
    asyncRendering: undefined,
    async: true,
    reqID: '',
    globalOptions: false,
    themeOptions: false,
    customCode: false,
    dataOptions: false,
    id: 1
  },
  working: true,
  ready: false,
  alive: true,
  process: <ref *1> ChildProcess {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      uncaughtException: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      close: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    _eventsCount: 3,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _closesNeeded: 3,
    _closesGot: 0,
    connected: false,
    signalCode: null,
    exitCode: null,
    killed: false,
    spawnfile: '/home/myhome/bin/phantomjs',
    _handle: Process {
      onexit: [Function (anonymous)],
      pid: 13480,
      [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
    },
    spawnargs: [
      '/home/myhome/bin/phantomjs',
      '/home/myhome/Downloads/node-export-server/lib/../phantom/worker.js',
      '/home/myhome/Downloads/node-export-server/lib/../'
    ],
    pid: 13480,
    stdin: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: null,
      _server: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 7,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [Pipe],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    stdout: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: null,
      _server: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 8,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [Pipe],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    stderr: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: null,
      _server: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 9,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [Pipe],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    stdio: [ [Socket], [Socket], [Socket] ],
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  workStartTime: 1693384873697,
  ondone: [Function (anonymous)],
  workcount: 13,
  incoming: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'n" +
    'n' +
    '  phantomjs://code/worker.js:658 in loopn' +
    '{"filename":"test.png"}',
  id: 1,
  doDone: [Function: doDone],
  restart: [Function (anonymous)],
  work: [Function (anonymous)],
  allowRestart: true
}
Wed Aug 30 2023 10:41:15 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) [notice] phantom worker 1 - process was closed
Wed Aug 30 2023 10:41:15 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) [notice] terminating, killing all running phantom processes
```

In the png resulting file (same thing if its a pdf output), there is this error message:

```
Please complete the configuration by running node build.js in the export server root.
```

I launch `node build.js` but it asks me the same configuration questions when I used the `npm install` command ! So I accept again the license terms and answer by default to the other questions.

I launch again the command line :

```
export OPENSSL_CONF=/dev/null && highcharts-export-server --nologo 1 --logLevel 4 --infile test.js --outfile test.png --type png --width 500
```

It throws always the same error as above !

I tried to install node/npm/highcharts-export-server in many ways but I'm unable to use it.

Thanx for clues

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately:

1. Export Server on the master branch does not work with Highcharts versions `>10.3.3` ([issue link](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/403)) and with Node versions higher than 16 ([issue link](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/399)).
2. Export Server requires `--infile` argument in the CLI to be the first one.
3. PhantomJS has been deprecated for a few years now and a long list of issues is related to the Phantom-based Export Server which are extremely difficult to solve.

I encourage you to try out our latest version of the Export Server, which is based on the Puppeteer (a modern headless browser library) where this should no longer be an issue.

Here's a short setup guide: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server#puppeteer-version-information

You can clone the following branch: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/tree/enhancement/puppeteer and run `npm install` and you should be ready to go.

Do not hesitate to ask in case you encounter other problems with the newest version.

Comment: Thanx, I tried to use it but no luck, it doesnt works. The installation is fine, but there is no highcharts-export-server script available. I found cli.js in this directory : node_modules/highcharts-export-server/bin/cli.js and it throws an error when I launch it with infile and outfile parameters (line 1: /bin: Is a directory, line 3: Highcharts: command not found, line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `c', line 5: `Copyright (c) 2016-2023, Highsoft')

Comment: my command line was : node_modules/highcharts-export-server/bin/cli.js -infile test.js --outfile test.pdf --type pdf

Comment: 1. You're right - you should run `node ./bin/cli.js --infile test.json --outfile test.png`;
2. That's because the accepted infile format files are JSON and SVG. For now, you cannot pass JavaScript files like that (the only exception is the callback.js file you can pass with the --callback option [you can update your chart in the callback]). There's already an open feature request on GitHub for exporting with code execution: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/346 which will be taken care of right after all the priority issues related to server health are solved.